# How can I run a script after a specific package is upgraded?

Tags: apt

I created a systemd service for an app as it does not include one, I would like to be able to restart the associated services when the package is updated.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 11):

AFAIK apt does not have package-specific hooks (i.e., there's no way to tell it to run a command when a given package is modified). What it does have is `DPkg::Pre-Install-Pkgs`:

```
Pre-Install-Pkgs
   This is a list of shell commands to run before invoking dpkg(1).
   Like options this must be specified in list notation. The commands
   are invoked in order using /bin/sh; should any fail APT will abort.
```

Note that this is run *before* anything is done with the packages.

You can specify a version for the information passed to the command via stdin; the level of information increases with the version:

- Version 1 just sends the paths to the package files being installed
- Version 2 additionally dumps

  - `VERSION 2` as the first line, then
  - the current Apt configuration, followed by a blank line

  and for each package,

  - the versions of the package before and after the operation,
  - as well as the operation itself, so, unlike Version 2,
- Version 3 in addition to the information in (2) adds architecture information (and has `VERSION 3` as the first line)

For a simple case, you could have a script like (in, say `/usr/local/bin/restart-foo`):

```bsh
#! /bin/bash

if grep -q my-package
then
    # schedule an at job to restart it
    at now + 30 min <<<"service restart foo"
fi
```

And apt configuration in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99-foo-hook`:

```
DPkg::Pre-Install-Pkgs {"/usr/local/bin/restart-foo";};
DPkg::Tools::Options::/usr/local/bin/restart-foo::Version "1";
```

For a more complex case, you can request more information and parse it, by setting `DPkg::Tools::Options::/usr/local/bin/restart-foo::Version` to `"2"` or `"3"`, like so:

```bsh
#! /bin/bash
declare -gA version action ver_index
ver_index["VERSION 2"]=3
ver_index["VERSION 3"]=5
skip_options ()
{
    while IFS= read -r line && [[ -n "$line" ]]
    do
        :
    done
}

IFS= read line
case $line in
    "VERSION "[23])
        ver_index="${ver_index[$line]}"
        skip_options
        while read -ra pack
        do
            echo "${pack[@]}"
            version["${pack[0]}"]="${pack[$ver_index]}"
            action["${pack[0]}"]="${pack[-1]}"
        done
        ;;
    *)
        while read pack ver
        do
            version["$pack"]="$ver"
            action["$pack"]="**CONFIGURE**"
        done < <( (echo "$line"; cat ) | xargs -d '\n' dpkg-deb --show --showformat='${Package} ${Version}\n')
        ;;
esac

for i in "${!version[@]}"
do
    echo "$i" "${version[$i]}" "${action[$i]}"
done
```

Of course, instead of `echo`ing the data, you'd use it to decide what to do.

Examples of input provided:

V1:

```
/var/cache/apt/archives/tcsh_6.18.01-5_amd64.deb
```

V2:

```
VERSION 2
APT::Architecture=amd64
APT::Build-Essential::=build-essential
APT::Install-Recommends=true
[...]
DPkg::Progress-Fancy=1
Binary=apt
CommandLine::AsString=apt%20install%20--reinstall%20tcsh

tcsh - < 6.18.01-5 /var/cache/apt/archives/tcsh_6.18.01-5_amd64.deb
tcsh - < 6.18.01-5 **CONFIGURE**
```

Version 3:

```
VERSION 3
APT::Architecture=amd64
APT::Build-Essential::=build-essential
APT::Install-Recommends=true
[...]
DPkg::Progress-Fancy=1
Binary=apt
CommandLine::AsString=apt%20install%20--reinstall%20tcsh
tcsh 6.18.01-5 amd64 none = 6.18.01-5 amd64 none /var/cache/apt/archives/tcsh_6.18.01-5_amd64.deb
tcsh 6.18.01-5 amd64 none = 6.18.01-5 amd64 none **CONFIGURE**
```

---

The other way around is to use dpkg triggers. For this, however, you will need to create a package which installs a trigger for something from the package you want to watch, but the triggers are executed after the package is configured, so this is better for restarting services. This [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15276537/2072269) has a good guide to that.